# Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:19)

Tags: react-native

web  Failed to compile.
C:/XXX/node_modules/galio-framework/src/Toast.js 11:19
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:19)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
| class Toast extends Component {

> static propTypes = {
>   |     children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
>   |     isShow: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,

```
{
  "name": "Bay",
  "version": "1.3.0",
  "description": "Desc",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "postinstall": "jetify"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://gx.git"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^35.0.0",
    "expo-asset": "~7.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~7.0.0",
    "galio-framework": "^0.6.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.10",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.3.0",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.6.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.3.0",
    "react-native-screens": "1.0.0-alpha.23",
    "react-native-unimodules": "0.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.4",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "argon react native",
    "argon design system",
    "argon app react native",
    "argon iOS",
    "react native iOS",
    "creative tim",
    "argon Android",
    "react native ui kit",
    "react native expo",
    "freebie",
    "react native argon design",
    "react native galio",
    "galio argon free",
    "galio react native free app",
    "argon expo react native",
    "react native ui template"
  ],
  "author": "ss",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/creativetimofficial/argon-react-native/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://demos.creative-tim.com/argon-react-native"
}
```

Comment: can you share your `webpack.config.js` ?

Comment: @kenmistry i'm new to react native.there is no file on project location with name webpack.config.js
.am i missed any npm plugins  for webpack ?

Comment: if the `webpack.config.js` file is not there, it is strange that you are facing this issue since installing `webpack` should initially set up the file for you. and it can be the command you have executed containing the `webpack`. perhaps, removing any `webpack` command should resolve the issue.

Comment: @kenmistry what kind of   `webpack` command remove from the project directory to resolve the issue

Comment: what command did you run that is causing this issue? for example, if it is `npm start`, go to `package.json` and look under `scripts`. remove any `webpack` words you see under `start: ...`. if it doesn't work, can you share your `package.json` above? i'll take a look.

Comment: @kenmistry  take a look at  `package.json`

Comment: can you do an uninstall of `webpack` and try running the previous command? how did `webpack` get listed as a dependency if there are no `webpack` commands under `scripts` and no `webpack.config.js` file present?

Comment: @kenmistry no `webpack` commands under `scripts` and no `webpack.config.js`.updated question along with `package.json` . take a look at the same

Comment: `webpack` is still listed as a dependency. can you uninstall it and remove all `node modules` before doing a reinstallation? thanks.

Comment: can you give `npm` command to uninstall `webpack`.
`npm uninstall` for removing all node modules right ?

Comment: firstly, `npm uninstall webpack` . secondly, `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` .

Comment: @kenmistry now getting new error  regarding `expo`.Expo sdk requires to run

Comment: you should set up a new question for this, since it is no longer relevant to the initial question. as for the initial question, i have added my above comments as an answer so you can accept it and close this question.

Comment: expo sdk error resolved by installing expo clii by the command `npm install -g expo-cli`.expo server should be start to run the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as discussed in the comments, there is no `webpack.config.js` to begin with. so, by removing `webpack` as a dependency, the above issue is resolved.

to remove `webpack` and perform a re-install, run the following command:

```
npm uninstall webpack && rm -rf node_modules && npm install
```

Answer (score 12):

If you are using Expo, I added the following to my app.json:

```
"web": {
  "build": {
    "babel": {
      "include": ["galio-framework"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It has worked after restarting the server