# How can I solve the Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:9) react-router-native

Tags: react-native, react-router-native

I installed react-native-router using yarn and just on importing NativeRouter

This is how I import from react-router-native
    import { NativeRouter, Route, Link } from "react-router-native";

This is the error I get

```
D:/WORKSHOP/Tunga/music-app/node_modules/react-router-native/NativeRouter.js 11:9
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|  */
| function NativeRouter(props) {
>   return <MemoryRouter {...props} />;
| }
|
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Had the same error. Fixed by adding:

```
"web": {
  "build": {
    "babel": {
      "include": ["react-router-native"]
    }
  }
}
```

to app.json

From: [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60181823/module-parse-failed-unexpected-token-1119)