# Expo Error for Web Version: ./node_modules/metro-runtime/src/modules/HMRClient.js 31:13

Tags: react-native, webpack, expo

I've been trying to get the web version of my expo react native app to work but get the following Error message when I try running it:

```
./node_modules/metro-runtime/src/modules/HMRClient.js 31:13
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (31:13)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
| class HMRClient extends EventEmitter {
>   _isEnabled = false;
|   _pendingUpdate = null;
|   _queue = [];
```

I spent a while doing research online and found a lot of other questions that addressed loader issues but could not figure out how solve this problem (possibly because I had trouble understanding their solutions).

(Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60181823/module-parse-failed-unexpected-token-1119) is the same issue? If so I'm not sure I understand how to resolve my issue using this answer).

Is there something that I can put in my `webpack.config.js` that can resolve this issue?